# Scripting an >= or in bash shell on a mac

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

The below code will return a result of 10.9.2

```
OSCHECK="$(sw_vers -productVersion)"
```

So running something like the below code works fine

```
OSCHECK="$(sw_vers -productVersion)"
if test "$OSCHECK" == "10.9.2"
then 
    echo "This Machine is 10.9.2 or above"
else
    echo "This Machine is 10.9.1 or below"
fi
```

However I would like it to be a bit more precise. I would like it to give me an equal or greater result. If I run the code below it doesn't give me the result I'm looking for, it passes the first command and returns an "else" result. What am I doing wrong?

```
OSCHECK="$(sw_vers -productVersion)"
if [ "$OSCHECK" >= "10.9.2" ];
then 
    echo "This Machine is 10.9.2 or above"
else
    echo "This Machine is 10.9.1 or below"
fi
```

Comment: This would be a duplicate if bash preformed the same way in mac as in unix

Comment: Yes, `bash` would behave similar to unix on mac (_at least in this case_).